# Running animation only once when the site is rendered for the very first time

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-hooks, react-router

The following is related to a react and react-router project I've been working on. I have an intro animation component which has to be rendered only once -- the very first time the app runs. the following is the code for running the animation:

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import RootLayout from "./layouts/RootLayout";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Errorpage from "./pages/Errorpage";
import Homepage from "./pages/Homepage";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AppIntro from "./components/AppIntro/AppIntro";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    errorElement: <Errorpage />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Homepage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        element: <About />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
const [isStarting, setIsStarting] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
setIsStarting(true);
[setIsStarting]);

return isStarting ? (
       <AppIntro setIsStarting={setIsStarting} />
     ) : (
       <RouterProvider router={router} />
     );
   }

export default App;
```

Note: What I mean by "the very first time," is the absolute first time when the app runs **only**. Not when the route is changed, or some other component from within the app is rendered for the first time. What I am specifically looking for is a pattern that is widely used for such purposes but any other workarounds will do as well.

Thanks for your time!

I tried leveraging the following pattern that I came across while I was learning react but it doesn't seem to be working. Ideally, it should be returning out of the useEffect second render onwards.

```
let introAnimationTrigger = true;

function App() {
const [isStarting, setIsStarting] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
if (introAnimationTrigger) {
introAnimationTrigger = false;
return;
}
setIsStarting(true);
[setIsStarting]);

return isStarting ? (
     <AppIntro setIsStarting={setIsStarting} />
   ) : (
     <RouterProvider router={router} />
   );
 }

export default App;
```

And the following is also something I tried but this too does not provide the desired result:

```
let introAnimationTrigger = true;

function App() {
const [isStarting, setIsStarting] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
if (introAnimationTrigger) {
setIsStarting(true);
introAnimationTrigger = false;
}

return () => {
if (!introAnimationTrigger) {
setIsStarting(false);
}
};
[setIsStarting]);

return isStarting ? (
     <AppIntro setIsStarting={setIsStarting} />
   ) : (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
   );
 }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the animation to run only once, the first time the app is mounted, and never again regardless how many times the `App` component is remounted or rerendered, then I suggest storing in localStorage that the animation has been run and check this persisted state.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [animationDidRun, setAnimationDidRun] = useState(() => {
    return !!localStorage.getItem("animationDidRun");
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!animationDidRun) {
      setAnimationDidRun(true);
      localStorage.setItem("animationDidRun", true);
    }
  }, [animationDidRun]);

  return animationDidRun ? (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  ) : (
    <AppIntro setIsStarting={setAnimationDidRun} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Of course, if a user clears their localStorage this will "reset" persisted state and the next time `App` mounts it will run the animation.

Comment: So, I initially thought of this solution but it is not what I am looking for. Perhaps I couldn’t quite explain my problem. Here is an example for the kind of animation I am aiming for: https://www.ideadesign.es/about/ 
Please note how the animation only runs once when the site starts and never again irrespective of the route changes until the site is visited again from scratch.

Comment: @SuryasishPaul That is what this solution *should* achieve for the most part. What doesn't work for your use case here? Oh, so when the app mounts again, you want to run the animation? Then the code in your initial code snippet should achieve that. If it's not, then perhaps you've still not clearly explained the use case and issue.

Comment: The problem with the localStorage solution (correct me if I'm wrong) is that the animation won't run after the absolute first time even when a user revisits the site unless the user clears the localStorage key and value. On the other hand, the problem with the my initial code is that the animation is running even on route changes. Both of these outcomes are undesirable. Basically, The animation must run only once every time the site is visited by a user and not when the route path changes.

Comment: Also, I have tried placing the animation component within a route page component but in that case the components of my layout such as the header and footer are visible during the animation which is unwanted. I have tried working around this issue by delaying the display of the layout components using a setTimeout() but in that case the setTimeout() runs on every route change.

Comment: @SuryasishPaul If the animation is running each running again each time the routes change then this appears to be an issue where the route changing is remounting the `App` component. Can you edit to add your routing code and how you are navigating around the app?

Comment: I have added the route definitions to my question for your reference. I haven't yet added the buttons and navigation code but the problem is occurring when I check the app by switching routes manually ("/about", "/" etc). The site is half-baked but I believe that shouldn’t affect the animation at the beginning. Really appreciate your help and please let me know if you need to have a look at anything else.

Comment: @SuryasishPaul I see. Well, when you are manually changing the URL in the browser's address bar, this is actually reloading the page, so it's like the app is mounting from scratch again each time. Once you implement in-app navigation using the `Link` component or the `useNavigate` hook the app won't reload when navigating.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for keeping patience. I am fairly new at coding and this has been very helpful. This should solve the problem I think.